# Remove item from list is while

Tags: python-3.x

Could someone help me understand why this code is returning the original items on the list instead of the items after user input name has been removed.

```
 lists = ['leo','bob','bob','Joe','Sam','Tracy','bob']
 counts = 0
 removeName = input(print("what name would you like to remove \n"))

 while counts != len(lists) and removeName not in lists :
     lists.remove(removeName)
     counts = counts + 1
print ("ok we removed all the", removeName, "from the list" ) 
print(lists)
```

Comment: `while removeName not in lists` and then `lists.remove(removeName)`.....

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me the same result.

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to remove the item from the list only if it's not actually there.

Comment: @Leofig123 Yeah that was my point sorry - it is exactly what you're doing. You're only trying to remove things if they aren't there.

Comment: @miradulo I see. So I put the "not in list" because if I just do the while counts != len(lists) : it will error when the loop does not have the item in list. So is there a better way for me to loop to remove items? I'm trying to figure out if I can do it without an if clause within the loop.

Comment: @miradulo thank you. Idk why I didn't realize that logic before posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the input() function you do not need to do print. Python will find the input from anything you put in that parameter, so first remove that print so it becomes:

```
removeName = input("what name would you like to remove \n")
```

Instead of:

```
removeName = input(print("what name would you like to remove \n"))
```

Next, you need to remember if an item in a list is removed, it is one item shorter. This means that if you remove an item, you don't want to change "counts". The final code should be:

```
lists = ['leo','bob','bob','Joe','Sam','Tracy','bob']
counts = 0
removeName = input("what name would you like to remove \n")
while counts != len(lists):
    if lists[counts] != removeName:
        counts = counts + 1
    else:
        lists.remove(removeName)
print ("ok we removed all the", removeName, "from the list" ) 
print(lists)
```